# Can I Grapple and Shove?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, grapple, prone

[I read a really cool multiclass on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/7vo2in/playing_a_bard_5e_advice/dttzzkx/), the Bardbarian, and I'm going to create one.

But it described a combination of Grapple and Shove to knock an enemy prone and not allow him to get up, since the grapple make his movements down to 0.

But how do I grapple a prone enemy?

Also, while grappling someone, do I take attacks from others with disadvantage?

Comment: I changed the link to directly reference the comment in question, and removed the `.amp` reference in the URL, as it was messing with the desktop presentation of the post. Also, I've made a few adjustments to the grammar to try to improve readability. If you feel I've mistakenly altered the intent or meaning of your post, feel free to rollback the changes I made using the [post history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/163499/revisions), or make [further edits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/163499/edit) to the post.

Comment: You seem to be asking a few totally different questions here; it seems like some of them may have been asked already, but I'm unable to find any duplicates at the moment.

Comment: If you want details on how you might grapple a prone enemy, try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw8gKycX-xE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### You can, being knocked prone doesn't stop you from being grappled

First of all, welcome to Stack Exchange!

As per grapple rules, emphasis mine:

> The target of your grapple **must be no more than one size larger than you and must be within your reach**. Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check [...]

No limitation on character state stated. To grapple a prone opponent, simply declare your grapple and roll the appropriate check.

However, the grapple's target isn't under any additional penalties to escape your grapple, as escaping a grapple doesn't require a movement action. Again, as per rules:

> Escaping a Grapple: A Grappled creature can use its action to escape. To do so, it must **succeed on a Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check** contested by your Strength (Athletics) check.

As for your second question, which could possibly be its own question entirely:

**Grappling does not apply any negative effects on the grappling character**

There's no rules stating otherwise that I can find.

Extra: A prone and grappled creature retains the following effect from **Prone**:

> An Attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the Attack roll has disadvantage.

Comment: It should be noted that while grappling, attempting to move, which would cause the grappled creature to be dragged or carried, reduces your speed by half.

Answer (score 2):

### Knocking someone prone is *de rigeuer* for grapplers

Independent of the specific classes, all grappler builds work towards knocking their opponent prone.

See [The grappler’s manual](https://www.enworld.org/threads/the-grapplers-manual-2-0-grappling-in-5th-edition.468737/).