# Grapple Shove or Shove Grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, grapple

In D&D 5e which is more efficient?

This came up as a discussion mostly because I've always seen this combo written out as "Grapple+Shove" and maybe it's just because it sounds better that way, but I thought it was better to Grapple and reduce the target's speed first and *then* Shove them to knock them prone.

My friends are saying that it would actually be easier the other way because then you would have advantage on the Grapple check if you shove the target prone first, and that seems right.

If the intention of the build is to knock the target prone, and keep them there, is there any case to be made for "Grapple then Shove" vs "Shove then Grapple"?

Comment: You say you are asking about which order would be more efficient, better, and easier.  These are not all necessarily the same thing.  Are you asking in which order it is **more likely** that you will end your attack with your target _both_ grappled and prone?  Perhaps you mean which combination is more effective?

Comment: Oops thanks Thomas, it's d&d 5e. And yes Kirt we were trying to determine if the intention of the build is to knock the target prone, and keep them there which order would should these moves happen in.

Comment: @zipperfist I've added the info from your comment into the question itself, since comments aren't guaranteed to stick around forever. Please feel free to edit further.

Comment: See ["Can I Grapple and Shove"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163499/26732).  Also, per that question, thanks to Dale M, ["The Grapplers Manual"](https://www.enworld.org/threads/the-grapplers-manual-2-0-grappling-in-5th-edition.468737/).

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson thanks for the edit, I've marked the below answer from Jack as correct after reviewing [The Grapplers Manual](https://www.enworld.org/threads/the-grapplers-manual-2-0-grappling-in-5th-edition.468737/) - It's just really weird that they use the terminology of attack when calling grappling a "special melee attack" even though it isn't an attack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It doesn't matter

> My friends are saying that it would actually be easier the other way because then you would have advantage on the Grapple check if you shove the target prone first, and that seems right.

Rules as written, you don't have advantage on Grapple when the target is already prone.

[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#Grappling) requires you to make an ability check:

> you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an attack roll: a Strength (Athletics) check contested by the target’s Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check

However, [prone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions#Prone) condition only affects attack rolls, not ability checks:

> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls.
> - An attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the attack roll has disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

### What if you fail?

As enkryptor has [already explained](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/210739/23547), neither order results in a greater chance of success.  Having a target Grappled does not advantage your Shove attempt, and having a target Prone does not advantage your Grapple attempt (because Grapple is a special melee attack, but it does not get an attack roll, and Prone gives advantage to the attack *rolls* of attackers.

However, there is another tactical consideration.  Given that you cannot be guaranteed that both your actions (Grapple and Shove, in either order) will succeed, and assuming that on the next turn you will attempt to continue your attempt to have the target both prone and grappled, order may still matter.

If both your attempts fail, it will not matter the order in which you attempted them.

If both your attempts succeed, it will not matter the order in which you attempted them.

If your first attempt succeeds, but your second fails, you will end your turn with your opponent either Grappled or Prone, but not both.  Thus the one you should attempt first is the one that is more advantageous for you to end your turn with.

If your first attempt fails, but your second succeeds, you will end your turn with your opponent either Grappled or Prone, but not both.  Thus the one you should attempt first is the one that is more advantageous of the two for you to end your turn with, and then when it fails, attempt it *again*.

Thus of the four possible cases (both fail, only the first fails, only the second fails, neither fails), in two cases order does not matter at all and in two cases you should attempt the more advantageous first, so that it is the one you have at the end of your turn.

#### If you can have only one

Which of the two conditions (Grappled or Prone) to impose first on your target depends on your ultimate goal.  OP says "the intention of the build is to knock the target prone, and keep them there".  But why?  Let's suppose the intention is to maintain them prone so that you and other melee fighters in your party can continue to attack them with advantage (while they have disadvantage), and that you are the only one in your party who is setting up these conditions even though others are benefitting from it.

Let us further suppose that every other member of your party who you are setting up, acts in initiative order before the target.  **In this case, it likely is better for you to knock the target prone first**.  If you can do only one thing, it is better to have the target prone for one round, with all the advantage that provides to your teammates, then to not have them prone at all.  On the target's turn, it it free to move, but it does have to use half its movement to stand up, so presumably it won't get too far before your turn, when you will move to it and begin the process again.  If you had, instead, grappled it, you would not have provided advantage to your teammates, and the best you could hope for is that it used its action to break the grapple.

On the other hand, suppose that the target's initiative comes immediately after yours, and before all of your other party members.  **In this case, it might be better to have Grapple be your first move.**  If you had knocked it prone, it would start its turn by standing up, and then either remain next to you using its action, or leave and facing no more than an opportunity attack from you (which might be unarmed).  You would not have provided advantage to any of your teammates.  If, instead, you Grappled it, then either it would still be in hand for you to attempt to take it prone on your next turn, or it would have to use its action to attempt to escape the Grapple, which might indirectly benefit your teammates.

If your target's initiative came before some of your teammates' initiatives and after others, than whether it would be more beneficial to open with Grapple or Shove would depend on how many of each there were, weighted by the marginal benefit of giving advantage to the ones that came before the target.